# MediaWiki - Resolve variables inside source tag

Tags: mediawiki

I have a template which receives a parameter that I use to define some variables. Even though I can resolve the parameter (eg.: `{{{PARAM}}}`) inside a `<pre>` or `<source>` tag, I cannot resolve variables (`{{#var:VAR1}}`). Here's an example that can be reproduced

```
{{#vardefine:TEST|asd}}

<source lang="bash">
export VAR={{#var:TEST}}
./execute args=$VAR
</source>
```

This results in the following page:

```
export VAR={{#var:TEST}}
./execute args=$VAR
```

But I was expecting it to result in:

```
export VAR=asd
./execute args=$VAR
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
{{#vardefine:TEST|asd}}

{{#tag:syntaxhighlight
|export VAR={{#var:TEST}}
./execute args=$VAR
| lang = "bash"
}}
```

Note:

- usage of the parser function `{{#tag:}}` used exactly in such cases, when it is necessary to parse the contents of the tag,
- `syntaxhighlight` rather than the deprecated `source`,
- that `lang` goes last. With other tags that would not be necessary, but in this tag the first argument will be treated as tag contents rather than attrubute, even though there is an equal sign in it.

Comment: I copied the exact same example you shared, but the wiki page did not render anything. Is there anything else I should do to have it rendered into the page?

Comment: I have checked the code before posting, it worked on my system. I can only suggest that you upgrade *MediaWiki*, *Variables* and *SyntaxHighlight*.

Comment: Ok, I'll take a look. Thanks.

Comment: Turns out our installation of MediaWiki does not support `#tag`. I'll mark your answer as correct since this might be relevant to other people searching for it.